# Excel: Reference row indicated by cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet where each row is a month and columns are monthly numbers.

I made a separate sheet for each month where the numbers from each month can be pulled together and added up.

To do this, I've made a template for January and used references like: `='2019'!A8`

I went through each month and changed the row number being referenced. ( `='2019'!A8` would change to `='2019'!A9` for the next month.)

Is it possible to pull the number for the reference from a different cell?

Could I have somehow referenced a cell which was just the number and used it for ='2019'!A#` Rather than change all my references by hand?

Comment: You might also consider putting all your data in one sheet and using a pivot table in another sheet to analyze it. I'm not clear on your design, but my experience is that designs like this with data spread across multiple sheets is hard to maintain and error-prone.

Comment: In my opinion, best solution is the one which is easy to maintain, update or change. I would not go for indirect references, but rather update my file structure to be more simple that does not require such formulas

Answer (score 0):

With a month indicator in each monthly sheet (say in D1 and `03` for March) then with all the monthly sheets grouped together my present understanding of what it is you want should be achieved with:

```
  =INDIRECT("2019!A"&$D1+7)
```

(Don't forget to ungroup.)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your data look like:

```
Month       Sales
January     500
February    1000
March       1500
...         ...
```

Moreover somewhere on your monthly sheets I suppose the month will be written in a cell, say `A1`.

Then you could simply use the same `VLOOKUP` on all these sheets:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1;SALES_DATA;2;FALSE)
```

And if your monthly sheets name contain the month name in some way, you could even do something like:

```
=VLOOKUP(MID(CELL("filename";A1);FIND("]";CELL("filename";A1))+1;255);SALES_DATA;2;FALSE)
```

`CELL("filename";A1)` retrieves the whole sheet path like `C:\Users\...\Desktop\[Sales.xlsm]March"`.